# Run a CountDownTimer inside an AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, countdowntimer

I need to run a piece of code 10 times at an interval of 3 seconds. Also, I want to run this on an AsyncTask because I don't want it to be tied to the activity.
So I did this:
1. Started an async task from my main activity.
2. I made my main activity is now waiting for the async task to be finished.
3. I started a CountDownTimer inside the AsyncTask to execute the desired piece of code at an interval of 3 seconds.
4. I have to update some UI elements in this piece of code. So, I am running that part on the UI thread.

Issue: I am getting the following error as soon as super( startTime, interval ) was called inside my CountDownTimer:

```
10-04 08:10:31.775  28124-28146/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:114)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:114)
```

Comment: You should use a [scheduler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory... doInBackground() runs on a background thread which, since it is not intended to loop, is not connected to a Looper.

You most likely don't want to directly instantiate a Handler at all... whatever data your doInBackground() implementation returns will be passed to onPostExecute() which runs on the UI thread.

ADDED FOLLOWING THE STACKTRACE APPEARING IN QUESTION:

Looks like you're trying to start an AsyncTask from a GL rendering thread... don't do that cos they won't ever Looper.loop() either. AsyncTasks are really designed to be run from the UI thread only.

So I would suggest you to make a method of the desired code needs to be run every minute and then set it with the timer.

for example:

```
private TimerTask mTimerTask;
private Timer t = new Timer();

public void doTimerTask() {

        mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        callYourMethodHere();
                        Log.i("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
        t.schedule(mTimerTask, 500, 1000); //

    }

    public void stopTask() {

        if (mTimerTask != null) {
            Log.i("TIMER", "timer canceled");
            mTimerTask.cancel();
        }

    }
```

Let me know if you find some problem by commenting below.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to have async task in my code so that the task keeps running even if the app is minimised by the user. Is your solution going to provide with a similar functionality?

Comment: then call Async Task in the timer. Make another AsyncTask and then put the desired code which needs to be run every minute and then call it in the timer(by mking its object and call it every minute) which is going to be run on Main Thread.

Comment: This isn't going to solve my problem because I need one AsyncTask which is going to enable me to run this piece of code even if the activity stops.

Comment: OK.. i got your problem. Simply create a Alarm Manager and set the timer. See the tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: If you want an example then also i will help you. Let me know if you require. but i would prefer you to see the tutorial first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91310/discussion-between-sangeeta-and-sid).

Comment: If you find this answer correct then please up vote it. :)

Comment: It actually didn't. :(

Comment: Then you should asked me na.. Not an issue.. is this problem is solved or still same?

Comment: I solved this problem, but with a different approach. I used a broadcast receiver instead which only calls this routine when it is required(instead of calling it again and again in a countDownTimer.

Comment: But I believe, for this question, the alarm manager approach would be a good one.

Comment: OK.. great.. we should try new things.. why dont you answer your own question so that we can also learn.. :)